# MetaProgramming in c++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am new to c++ and need help with metaprogramming. I have checked out the enum example wherein the call `factorial<4>::value` yields `24`.

What I need is a modification to the code so that `factorial<4>()` returns `24`. Have been trying it for quite some time now and do not know  how to exactly search for it on the internet too. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you !

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
template <int N>
struct factorial
{
    enum { value = N * factorial<N - 1>() };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Comment: You're going to need a function, functor, or some other callable object. Start with that.

Comment: Thanks @ghostofstandardspast , I'll look into it. Never worked with functors before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `constexpr` function:

```
template<int N>
constexpr int factorial() {
    return N * factorial<N - 1>();
}

template<>
constexpr int factorial<0>() {
    return 1;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3b4ae8715995540)

This will allow you to call:

```
factorial<4>();
```

and get `24` as a returned value.

---

Alternatively you can use the implicit conversion operator `operator int()` to perform an implicit conversion, of the `struct` to `int`:

```
template<int N>
struct factorial {
    static const int value = N * factorial<N-1>::value;
    operator int() { return value; }
};

template<>
struct factorial<0> {
    static const int value = 1;
    operator int() { return value; }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/427bccb5d3b8d2f1)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jefffrey. But I am not able to understand the error (never used constexpr) : expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before 'int'

Comment: @Noob What code are you running? Paste it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and then click "Share" on the bottom right. Moreover, if you click on "Live demo", you can see the correct usage of the given solution.

Comment: @Noob, `constexpr` is a C++11 feature. Make sure you have C++11 enabled.

Comment: @Noob Yeah, that might be it. You can use the `-std=c++11` compiler flag to enable C++11.

Comment: Thanks .. I just did that !

Comment: Why should he use a function? It seems he doesn't know how to implement a factorial using the class as shown above (he's doing  `N * factorial<N - 1>()` instead of `N * factorial<N - 1>::value`). If anything, this is just an alternate way of doing the above.

Comment: @0x499602D2 "What I need is a modification to the code so that `factorial<4>()` returns `24`" -- This is not possible declaring `factorial` as a `struct` while keeping the compile time behavior. If you have found a way, feel free to post it.

Comment: @jeffrey: "not possible defclaring `factorial` as a struct`... just have to add `constexpr operator int() const { return value; }` members - see http://ideone.com/bFVyMR

Comment: @TonyD Touché. Added.

Comment: The notation may be even shorter (without brackets) if you use C++14 variable templates: `template <int N> constexpr int fact = factorial<N>::value;`.

Answer (score 4):

To just use the function call like a function call, you need to use `constexpr` (a new addition to C++11). Note that when you *do* use this, you do *not* need to use a template at all though. Though there are some limitations, the basic syntax is that of a normal function:

```
int constexpr fact(int x) { return x == 0 ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1); }
```

This is still computed at compile time though. For example, if you wanted to use it to specify the size of an array, you could do so:

```
int main(){
    int array[fact(5)];
}
```

Likewise, you can use such a result as a case in a switch statement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int constexpr fact(int x) { return x == 0 ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1); }

int main(int agc, char **argv){
    switch (std::atoi(argv[1])) {
    case fact(1) :
    case fact(2):
    case fact(3):
    case fact(4):
    case fact(5):
        std::cout << "You entered a perfect factorial";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "I'm not sure about that";
    }
}
```

[compiled/tested with gcc 4.8.1]

Comment: Pedantic remark concerning "This is still computed at compile time though": unless the compiler is forced to evaluate the function call at compile-time (as it is in your example), there is no guarantee that the expression will indeed be evaluated at compile-time.